# Identify a book about a sailing expedition where they find fantasy creatures

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember encountering a book when I was a child about 25 years ago. It was illustrated and they were on a sailing expedition where they find a land filled with fantasy creatures. There were griffins that hunted unicorns, the unicorns had flat horns and were brown furred. They found a sea serpent washed ashore that had baleen and apparently was a filter feeder. And they found a dead dragon that had died from burn marks probably from another dragon. I can't for the life of me figure out what that book was called. Is anybody familiar with it?

Comment: When did you read this?  We don't know when you were a child.

Comment: I'm 35 and it was elementary school, I don't remember which grade

Comment: @AaronAbel age ranges would be good, because not everyone is American and thus not everyone knows what age you were in "elementary school" or in a particular grade.

Comment: A range of calendar years would be nice.

Comment: (Different countries and generations have different ways of referring to school years — such as Year 10, fifth grade, second form, 1st year of middle school, Lower Sixth, 2nd year juniors, reception — and I bet few here could translate _all_ of them unaided!)

Comment: I believe I was around 12

Comment: 35 minus 12 equals 23 years so about 2000-2001 give or take a few years.

Comment: This reminds me of 1996's "The Voyage of the Basset" but the only art of a unicorn from it I can find shows it white furred with a pointed horn.

Comment: I checked just in case and that's not it, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like the 1996 fantasy novel [Voyage of the Bassett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Basset)

There was a movie made from it called [Voyage of the Unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Unicorn) with Beau Bridges.

The parts that seem to match:

I remember encountering a book when I was a child about 25 years ago.

> Check.  Was published in 1996 so available in 2000 - 2001.

It was illustrated and they were on a sailing expedition where they find a land filled with fantasy creatures.

> Check. The Aislings set sail on a magical voyage where they meet a number of creatures from mythology that join them on board the ship.

There were griffins that hunted unicorns, the unicorns had flat horns and were brown furred. They found a sea serpent washed ashore that had baleen and apparently was a filter feeder.

> Partial Check? It has been 25 years since I read it as well so I don't remember the details as to exactly what the unicorns were like.  But am pretty sure there were at least unicorns. They also had manticores, trolls, faeries, and a sphinx which is somewhat like a griffin in that both a sphinx and a griffin have the body of a lion and wings of an eagle. I don't remember a sea serpent in the book (though as I said it has been a long time).  But I am pretty sure the film version had one at some point.

And they found a dead dragon that had died from burn marks probably from another dragon.

> Possible check. In one part there is a dragon that burns the leaders of the trolls.

Below is a picture of the cover:

[image: Voyage of the Basset]

Comment: I checked, that's not it. Thanks though